# ContourPlot3D in spherical coordinates

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

Is it possible to define/code a new plot in 3D directly using *Spherical coordinates* imagined to be somewhat like:

```
ContourPlot3Dsph[{f[r,theta,phi]==0}, {phi,.5,3}, {theta,0,3}, {r,1,2}]
```

Although we may convert from *Cartesian coordinates*, the advantage would be to see surface with net of parametric lines  $\phi= c_1, \theta=c_2, r= c_3 $ varied. It helps slightly better visualization of surface radial buildup due to $r$ variation, or so I feel.

EDIT1:

i.e., while visualizing the surface I want to be able to see Gridlines/Net defined on spherical coordinates, but not as the usual slices of Cartesian cuts.The parametric lines are a set of cones having common vertex at origin $\phi$, a set of meridians $\theta$, a set of sphere radii $r$.

Comment: You can use the substitution `ro=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2], fi=...` putting these formulas directly inside the `f(...)`. It will be like `f(Sqrt[..],ArcTan[..], ArcTan[..])` and it will work with usual `ContourPlot3D` where the variables are `{x,x0,x1}, {y,y0,y1},{z,z0,z1}`.

Comment: You can post a new question and someone should post another answer. BTW,edit2 should be a surface instead of solid.

Comment: Thanks , posting separately as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need define mesh functions for spherical coordinates.

For r:

```
ContourPlot3D[x + y - z == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    Mesh -> {{.8, 1, 1.3}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]}]
```

[image]

For phi and theta:

```
ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   Mesh -> {{0 Degree, 10 Degree, -70 Degree}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, ArcTan[x, y]]}]

ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   Mesh -> {{20 Degree, 90 Degree, 120 Degree}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]}]
```

With additional RegionFunction, you can e.g. restrict for 60 Degree < theta < 150 Degree

```
ContourPlot3D[x + y - z == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    Mesh -> {{.8, 1, 1.3}}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]}, 
    RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
    60 Degree < ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] < 150 Degree]]
```

Comment: When only $\phi, \theta$ are parametrized we have a surface.When  $r, \phi, \theta$ are parametrized we have a  solid, or hollow solid.if meshed.